# How to create new list based on the original list same values but different index

Tags: python, list, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I have a GUI interface created using **Pyqt5** in Python it import an Excel file and display its columns as items in the **listWidget**. Where the user can check the items and each checked item its appended to the **new_list**.

The problem is that if I have the below example:

```
original_list = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
```

If user select for the **new list** the below items:

**"C", "f", "a"**

## The result:

```
new_list = ["a","c","f"]
```

## The expected result:

```
new_list =  ["c","f","a"]
```

in this image the user select item at index 3 before the item at index 0 :
[image: in this image the user select item at index 3 before the item at index 0]

But the **new_list** append the item at index 0 before the item at index 3

## Code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import chardet




class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.header_list = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.header_list.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 1667))
        self.header_list.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
        self.header_list.setObjectName("header_list")
        self.header_list.itemChanged.connect(self.selectionChanged)
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")

        self.menufile = self.menubar.addMenu("File")
        self.menufile.setObjectName("menufile")

        self.menuimportfile = QtWidgets.QAction("Import File",self.menufile)
        self.menuimportfile.setObjectName("importfile")
        self.menuimportfile.triggered.connect(lambda:self.loadFile())
        
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        
        self.menufile.addAction(self.menuimportfile)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.menufile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "file"))


    def loadFile(self):
        try:
            fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File", "", "Excel Files (*.csv *.xls *.xlsx)");
            print(fileName)            
            name, ext = os.path.splitext(fileName)
            print("name: {} ".format(name))
            print("ext:  {} ".format(ext))
            if ext == ".csv":
                with open(fileName, 'rb') as rawdata:
                    result = chardet.detect(rawdata.read(100000))
                print(result)
                df = pd.read_csv(fileName,encoding = result["encoding"])
            elif ext == ".xls" or ext == ".xlsx":
                df = pd.read_excel(fileName)
            self.df = df

            
        #part that display items in the qlistWidget
            self.header_list.clear()
            savelist = list(self.df)
            for item in savelist:
                qitem = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem ( ) 
                qitem.setText ( item ) 
                qitem. setFlags ( QtCore. Qt . ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore. Qt . ItemIsEnabled ) 
                qitem.setCheckState ( QtCore.Qt.Unchecked ) 
                self.header_list.addItem ( qitem )
        
        except Exception as e:
            print("error is {}".format(e))

    def selectionChanged(self):
        self.checked = []
        
        for row in range(self.header_list.count()):
            item = self.header_list.item(row)
            #need to be checked in order to display the item in the order that the user choose.
            if item.checkState():
                if item in self.checked:
                    del self.checked[item]
                else:
                # if not item in self.checked: 
                    self.checked.append(item)
            
                
        # checked.insert(len(checked)-1,item)
        print("Checked items: ", ", ".join(i.text() for i in self.checked))
        self.checked = [i.text() for i in self.checked]




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the implementation of `selectionChanged` can be the line below.
Just iterate and collect the checked items.

```
def selectionChanged(self):
    self.checked = [self.header_list.item(row) for row in range(self.header_list.count()) if self.header_list.item(row).checkState()]
```

Comment: your answer gives the same result of my question and not the expected result

Comment: Just iterate and collect the checked items. but based on the item selected first means if the user select the item index 3 first in  `self.check[]` it will be item index 0

Comment: Do you want to collect the index of the selected items?

Comment: not not the index but what i mean is :  `list = ["car","bike","cell"]` the car has index 0 bike 1 cell 3 in my code i want if the user  `check first  bike`  then the `car`  ...the `self.check=["bike","car"]`   until now  the result displayed is what ever the user check first always the `self.check` is taking the values from `list` as its index is equal to.

Answer (score 0):

The `itemChanged` signal also sends *what* item has changed, and this can be used to manipulate the list.

Obviously, if you continuously create a new list, there's no easy way to track what was previously selected or not, so you need a *persistent* list and eventually append/remove items based on their check state.

Note that I've changed a bit the structure of your code (more about this later).

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.checked = []

    # ...

    def selectionChanged(self, item):
        if item.checkState():
            if item not in self.checked:
                self.checked.append(item)
        elif item in self.checked:
            self.checked.remove(item)
        print([i.text() for i in self.checked])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Besides the obvious need to create a list in the `__init__`, the modifications are due to the fact that what you're using is probably a modification of a file generated by `pyuic`: those files should **never** be modified (nor you should try to imitate their behavior), should always be used as they are, and only as imported files.
Even in that case, you're creating `Ui_MainWindow` as a subclass of QMainWindow, but you're not actually using it as such. There's no actual benefit in doing so, and it only makes things more complex than they should. My suggestion is to recreate the ui file with pyuic, then import it in your script, *remove the `setupUi` in the current code* and subclass the main window from both QMainWindow and the Ui_MainWindow of the imported file; assuming the file is exported as `ui_MainWindow.py`, your code will become the following:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from ui_MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.checked = []
        self.header_list.itemChanged.connect(self.selectionChanged)
# ...
```

You can read more about correctly using those files in the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Finally, I strongly suggest you to use [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html) otherwise all your widgets will become unusable if the window is too small, or a lot of space will be unused if the window is bigger.

Comment: thanks for the help and explanation but i tried your function and it still return the same result not the expected one

Comment: @RanyFahed The code works, so ensure that you've correctly applied the changes I made and that you're not constantly recreating the list.

Comment: what you mean by **you're not constantly recreating the list **

Comment: @RanyFahed As already explained in the answer, in your code you create a new `self.checked` list everytime the `selectionChanged` is called. This is clearly wrong, as it won't allow you to keep track of the previously checked items in their correct order. If you look at my code, the `self.checked` list is only created *once*, in the `__init__`.

Comment: i do not want to keep track of the previously checked items . what i want is to once I have the items in the `header_list` that will be **created once** but the `self.checked` its created every time....... so you mean the `self.checked` can't be created evertime ??

Comment: You want to keep track of the order the user checks the items, right? Because that's what you asked in your question. If you want to know the order, you *must* use a persistent list, if you create a new list everytime there's absolutely no way to know the order.